# Python implmentation of Marginal Maximum Likelihood estimate based 2-PL Dichotomous IRT

Tags: python, statistics, estimation, log-likelihood, jamovi

I am looking for implementations of simple Marginal Maximum Likelihood Estimate based 2-PL IRT Item estimation in Python. Any relevant Python libraries that do this (similar to snowIRT module in Jamovi)? I have looked into py-irt and it seems to do a Variational Inference based estimate of the parameters. I wanted something very simple for Marginal MLE and a dichotomous 2-PL IRT.

Thank You!